# Make iTunes handle albums with different artists

Tags: itunes, music, id3-tag

I'm a big fan of ocremix.org and I have quite a few tracks from that community. However, when looking at my music in Album view, it seems to be fairly arbitrary as to how it combines artist and album name when creating its groupings.

Is there a way to force iTunes to combine all songs with the same album name into the same album in album view, regardless of the artist? Ideally I'd like to have a single ocremix.org album which I could open up and sort by artist.

Also, ocremix.org has a convention when multiple artists are participating in a single track to list them all out, separated by commas. Can iTunes handle this in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the files you want to combine, make a right click and select "Information", go to tab "Options" and set "part of a compilation" to yes...

Comment: I picked 6 at random and it worked for 4 out of the six. The other 2 were already grouped for some reason. This is a great start! :D

Comment: Those two already had an "Album Artist." When I cleared that, all six went into a single group. :) And I'll accept when the time limit has passed.

Comment: Ah ok, I've forgotten the the limit ^^ sorry

Answer (score 1):

This blog article deals exhaustively of this specific topic : http://www.blisshq.com/music-library-management-blog/2011/03/26/five-ways-organize-various-artist-compilations/

To sum up :
  - as stated by strauberry, declare all files part of a compilation
  - decide of a string that define your various artists albums (something such as 'Various') and set it as 'album artist' tag value
  - keep compilation, album name, year and album artist tags identical